# Настройка и работа в eclipse с tomcat -ом для чайников

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, книги, настройка

*Такое ощущение, что программистам нужно быть ещё и сисадминами*

Вообщем учу сервлеты. Недавно написал наипростейщий сервлет для первого опыта. С горем пополам скомпилировал, так же написал конфиг, так же расположил структуру. Всё равно не заработало. Так и не решил.

Вообщем задолбало делать всю работу ручками. Решил поставить ide. Опять не могу разобраться. Нужен какой-то туториал. Сам ничего не нашёл.

Вот и вопрос - **Подскажите пожалуйста туториал по сопряжению eclipse с tomcat -ом. Причём максимально длячайневский :).**

p.s. english тоже сойдёт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Откопал с трудом [Java EE (J2EE) Tutorial for beginners Part5](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSS0Tndfh6I&list=PLHqN89yRGMyAcwWcSWk59_S_-BQVn3Rrb)